# Deleting devicemapper after changing storage driver

Tags: linux, docker, device-mapper

Long time listener, first time caller.

I've inherited a CI box running docker and I'm looking to clear some space. Running `docker info` tells me that the current storage driver is `overlay`. Despite that, I can see `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper` still exists and its eating up 10G of space.

With that in mind, is it safe to delete this folder? How can I tell if there are any references to this?

Thanks for your help!

Nick

Comment: What is the output of `findmnt /var/lib/docker/devicemapper` ?

Comment: `findmnt` returns nothing in this case.

Comment: And `sudo dmsetup status` ?

Comment: That returns `No devices found`

Comment: You can safely remove the directory.

Comment: Legend, thank you!